# Python Django tables with checkbox delete option

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django and currently trying to display a table with a checkbox which displays the list of records from the database and would have a delete button to delete multiple records using checkbox.

How to display a table with checkbox and delete button?

Appreciate your help!

Here is my code related to it:

#### models.py

```
class Customer(TimeStamp):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,help_text="Long-form name (optional)")
    comments = models.TextField(blank=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-id']

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('App_CUS:customer_list')
```

#### views.py

```
class CustomerListView(ListView):
    queryset = Customer.objects.order_by('id')
    model = Customer
    paginate_by = 10
    context_object_name = 'customers'
    template_name = 'App_CUS/customer_list.html'
```

#### customer_list.html

```
customer_list.html:
{% extends 'index.html' %}
{% load buttons %}

{% block content %}
<div class="pull-right">
    {% if perms.App_CUS.customer_add %}
        {% add_button 'App_CUS:customer_add' %}
        {% delete_button 'App_CUS:customer_delete' %}
    {% endif %}
</div>
<h1>{% block title %}Customers{% endblock %}</h1>
<div class="col-md-9">
<div class="table-responsive">
  <table class="table table-hover table-headings table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="pk">
            <input class="toggle" title="Toggle all" type="checkbox">
        </th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Description</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for customer in customers %}
        <tr>
        <th class="pk">
            <input class="toggle" title="Toggle all" type="checkbox">
        </th>
          <td>{{ customer.pk }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ customer.description }}</td>
        </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add to your existing

```
{% for customer in customers %}
```

a new td tag including something like:

```
<td>
   <div class="checkbox">
                <input type="checkbox" name="name_check_{{customer.name}}" id="id_check{{customer.name}}"  value="1"
                    {%if customer.data == 0 %}unchecked {%else%} checked {%endif%}>     
  </div>
<td>
```

I've used customer.data to represent a value stored in your db.

You could then write some js to do something on click of each new checkbox.

```
<script>                                                                    
  $(document).ready(function() {
     $("#id_check_{{customer.id}}").on("click", function(){
        #do something / ajax call etc..
```

OR

pass these values back to the view on form post (we've named each checkbox unique to the customer), then process the deletions from there.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your swift response. Is there any django built in stuff/best practices for this kind of requirement because, I need to have this feature on lot of other pages to delete mutliple records( customers, stores, products etc.). I tried using django-tables2, however, couldn't get there.